# Using Union to display two columns

Tags: union

I am trying to use UNION to collect data from two tables, however, the results combine both rows of information into one long column. I've spent a few hours researching unions and I cannot find a code that separates the result! I am using microsoft Access, and would like to use UNION if it possible. Please help...

My code is:

```
SELECT Suburb 
FROM Customer
UNION 
SELECT TotalPaid 
FROM SalesOrder
ORDER BY Suburb;
```

An example of my result is:

```
Suburb
0
128
Brighton
Kings Cross
```

But I need it to show:

```
Suburb         Total Paid
Brighton       0
Kings Cross    128
```

Answer (score 0):

No need of Union,Hope you have relation on suburb between two tables.

```
   SELECT c.Suburb ,TotalPaid 
FROM Customer as c
left join SalesOrder as s on c.Suburb  = s.Suburb 
ORDER BY c.Suburb;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but your code doesn't return the result I am looking for.